# Send and read result of an At command to a usb modem in c#

Tags: c#, .net, modem, at-command

I would like to know how to send and receive the result of an AT command sent to a usb modem.

I've found lot of info, but I don't know what is the best way:

I've found this : 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxnetcom/thread/800f12fa-4da8-42bf-b61b-65f6bb58c871/

But I've found the write and read kind of weird...

Somebody have something else ?

Thanks all !

EDIT :

not sure the link I paste was very great i've tried it and it gave me a null exception.

Now i'm trying this :

```
 SerialPort sp = new SerialPort();
            sp.PortName = "COM3";
            sp.Open();
            sp.Write("AT<CR>");
```

But I really don't know how to read the result, someone have an idea ?

Comment: `sp.Read` should do the trick.  You'll have to have a modem that support communicating with it via a COM port, and you'll have to have the right COM port set up in your program to match your modem's settings

Comment: Yeah I saw this one, but the thrid parameters count messed me up, how can I know how much byte will I have to read ?

Comment: You don't.  Just make a big-ish buffer and pass the size of that.  Like `var buffer = new byte[4096];`.  The return value from the function will tell you how many bytes were read into the buffer.

Comment: @Greg You could use sp.BytesToRead to know how many bytes to read

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(sorry for my bad english)

I'm doing exactly the same thing in a WPF app, just hook up the sp.DataReceived event and there you could use `sp.ReadExisting()` to get the data.

Comment: Ok found this : http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/csharp/threads/232090 , i'm trying it right now. try to be more explicative nextime :), but +1 for now

Comment: @Greg If it helped you to find how to resolve your problem, I think it is good enough - I have a working application that communicate with an USB modem, if you have any other question I will be glad to help.